# Silverstipe tutorial - addFieldToTab does not work

Tags: silverstripe

I am following silverstripe tutorial number 2: Extending a basic site http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/2-extending-a-basic-site

I have downloaded ss3.0.3 and using Windows 7 WAMP 2.1

I have created the ArticlePage and ArticleHolderPage but when I go and create a page of type ArticleHolder there are no date and author fields in the content tab.

My code for the ArticlPage:

```
class ArticlePage extends Page
{
    static $db = array(
         'Date'=>'Date',
         'Author'=>'Text'
      );

   public function getCMSFields()
   {
      $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

      $dateField = new DateField('Date');
      $dateField = setConfig('showcalendar', true);
      $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $dateField, 'Content');
      $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('Author'), 'Content');

      return $fields;
   }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: no apparent reason, the code you provided is perfectly valid. did you run dev/built? have you tried to add '?flush=1' to the admin url?

Answer (score 2):

oh, i was too quick with my comment above, just found an error in your code:

```
$dateField = setConfig('showcalendar', true);
```

should read

```
$dateField->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
```